# Get the shortest Path in .tiff map

Tags: c++, tiff, dijkstra, slam

I am working with SLAM to build of an environment. I do this with a Lidar sensor and it's working pretty cool. Now I have a map of the environment in .tiff format. I want to find the shortest path(Dijkstra) from a point A to B, but my problem is I don't know how to convert this .tiff map in a format I can work with. I code in C++.

Do anyone has an idea how I could do this?

Thanks :)

edit:

The [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwc6l.png) looks like this. The black pixels are obstacles and the grey ones are space to move.

Comment: What exactly is the contents of this TIFF image? Can you post an example?

Comment: Yeah thank you very much. Sorry I am new in this community and don't know all the rules yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, if you are allowed to diddle your data *"pre-flight"*, you could use **ImageMagick** to convert your TIFF file to an extremely simple PGM file. **ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

The PGM format is very simple, and is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). As your image is 400x300, it will look like this:

```
P5
400 300
255
120,000 unsigned char bytes of image data - uncompressed, unpadded
```

You would convert your TIFF file like this:

```
convert map.tif -normalize -threshold 1 map.pgm
```

and then you can read 3 lines of header and then directly read your 120,000 bytes into an array. This way, you have no need for extra libraries or software on your platform.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use `CImg` - [link here](http://cimg.eu). It is C++ and very lightweight and easy to use as it is implemented as *"header only"* - so you just download and include the single file `CImg.h` and you are ready to go.

This code will read your TIF map and allow you to access the pixels:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
   // Load the map
   CImg<unsigned char> map("map.tif");

   // Get and print its dimensions
   int w = map.width();
   int h = map.height();
   cout << "Dimensions: " << w << "x" << h << endl;

   // Iterate over all pixels displaying their RGB values
   for (int r = 0; r < h; r++){
      for (int c = 0; c < w; c++){
         cout << r << "," << c << "=" << (int)map(c,r,0,0) << "/" << (int)map(c,r,0,1) << "/" << (int)map(c,r,0,2) << endl;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Dimensions: 400x300
0,0=94/94/94
0,1=100/100/100
0,2=88/88/88
0,3=89/89/89
0,4=89/89/89
0,5=89/89/89
0,6=89/89/89
0,7=89/89/89
0,8=89/89/89
0,9=89/89/89
0,10=89/89/89
0,11=89/89/89
0,12=89/89/89
0,13=89/89/89
0,14=89/89/89
0,15=93/93/93
0,16=101/101/101
....
....
```

Set your compilation flags like this to include built-in support (without ImageMagick) for TIFF:

```
g++ -Dcimg_use_tiff ... -ltiff
```

You will need to have installed `lib tiff`.

If you are not interested in colour, you can convert the image to black and white so it is just a single channel rather than three, and threshold it so you just have pure blacks and pure whites that may be easier to deal with. Just add this code at the end of the code above:

```
// Convert to single channel black and white
CImg<unsigned char> bw = map.get_RGBtoYCbCr().channel(0);
bw.normalize(0,255).threshold(1).normalize(0,255);

// Now get pointer to black and white pixels, or use bw(x,y,0)
unsigned char* data=bw.data();

bw.save_png("result.png");
```

[image]

There's actually a `dijkstra` method in `CImg` but I cannot work out how to use it at the moment - if anyone knows, please tag me in a comment! Thanks.

Comment: Cool example and great to know about CImg.

Comment: @BruceDean Thank you, kind sir!